# imwrite in matlab change the actual image data

Tags: matlab

Below is the Matlab script to read and write (copy) an image using imwrite. I expect the newly written file to be same as the original file but the images and their histogram vary. The script is as under

```
%=====================================================================%
I = imread('lena.jpg');
I = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.05);
I = im2double(I);

figure, imshow(I);
figure, imhist(I);

[M,N] = size(I);
J = I;
for i = 1 : M
    for j = 1 : N
        J(i,j) = I(i,j);
    end
end
imwrite(J,'I1.png'); %tried with jpg and bmp, but same result
J = imread('I1.jpg');

figure, imhist(J); 

%=====================================================================%
```

[image: Histogram of expected same images]

Kindly help to make me understand why these images vary

Comment: `imwrite(J,'I1.png'); J = imread('I1.jpg');` You're reading in a different image than what you write out...

Comment: Yes, thank you for highlighting the mistake but I originally used .jpg for both write and read and that showed me variation in histograms. Let me check for .png by correcting the extension in imread()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code for Lena.jpg and Lena.png, for reading the input image and writing the output image. 
When using **.jpg**, the histograms are different. This compression format is [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), therefore it is expected that there is some loss of information. You must specify lossless when using imwrite if you want to prevent said loss.

```
imwrite(J,'I1.jpg','Mode','lossless');
```

When using **.png**, the histograms are the same as this compression format is [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: So, you mean I need to read from a lossless format (say, lena.png) originally if I want my output file I1.png to be same as lena.png. I will check it and update accordingly. Anyways thank you

Comment: That's correct. You can try with other lossless formats such as .tiff and you will find that the histograms are identical. You should be working with lossless formats anyway. You can actually use .jpg if you want, however you must specify 'lossless' mode when using imwrite. I have edited my answer with this change.